# Usage and meaning of “aufzeigen”

Tags: difference, verb

What is the difference between *aufzeigen* and *zeigen*? Both mean *to show*, and I guess *aufzeigen* could be more used in the spoken language maybe. Is it so? Is there a difference in the meaning?

> Ich zeige dir meine Noten.

and

> Ich zeige dir meine Noten auf.

I also found on Duden that *aufzeigen* has a special meaning in Austria, like *sich melden* (*get in touch*). The example I found was this one:

> Wer es weiß, soll aufzeigen.

But what would that mean in English? How could that be translated to English? *Whoever knows, get in touch*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Aufzeigen*, on the contrary, is slightly more formal than *zeigen* (it’s also used to mean *to raise a hand*, like pupils in a classroom, but this is not meant here). It means to display, to demonstrate, to point out. Obviously there is some overlap with *zeigen*.

If you have literally something to show you’ll probably want to use *zeigen*.
*Aufzeigen* is somewhat more abstract:

> Der Chemiker zeigte die Möglichkeit einer spontanen Reakion auf. 
> Der Geologe zeigte die Gefahr eines Bergsturzes auf.

*Wer es weiß, soll aufzeigen*. But what would that mean in English?

> Who knows the answer? Show of hands!

Comment: I would prefer *should put their hand up* rather than *show of hands* but maybe that’s just personal preference.

Comment: Obviously there's more than one way to skin a cat.

Comment: Please, refrain from skinning cats.

Answer (score 1):

In colloquial use and in the meaning of *to show*, you would only ever hear *zeigen*.

> In dieser Museumsführung werden Sie einige Werke von da Vinci und einige von Dürer *gezeigt* bekommen.
>
> Ich *zeige* dir den Weg, dann findest du alleine nach hause.
>
> Soll ich dir meine Briefmarkensammlung *zeigen*?

In all of these examples *aufzeigen* would raise two or more eyebrows. That verb is used a lot more in a scientific sense of *showing*, *proving* as Ingmar pointed out. It has a more formal taste to it than simple *zeigen* and in my opinion it is rarely used.

> Die Gruppe *zeigte* den Zusammenhang zwischen Alkohol und Betrunkenheit.
> Die Gruppe *zeigte* den Zusammenhang zwischen Alkohol und Betrunkenheit *auf*.

And finally, *aufzeigen* can mean *to put one’s hand up* in school, but I think that usage is regionally restricted to the South (-East?)

> Zehn Schüler *zeigten auf*; einer war so ungeduldig, dass er schnipsen musste.

Answer (score 0):

In Austrian German "aufzeigen" means "raising hands" in order to get someone's  attention. Usually this is used in school. Teacher asks a question and whoever knows the answer raises their hand. Teacher then picks someone.

Regarding your second question. "zeigen" means "to show" and aufzeigen is supposed to impress, e.g. a new young talented football player impresses with good performances, then you could say "Er hat mit seinen Leistungen aufgezeigt"

Comment: Hmm, I guess the latter use is Austrian only, then.

Comment: I agree with chirlu, and "aufzeigen" in the sense of "raising hands" in not specific to Austria.